# How can load thumbnail through Vimeo API?

Tags: objective-c, vimeo, vimeo-api

I need to load thumbnail for special video_id.
For it I use this link (video_id):
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/111096137

all time I get response
{
    "error": "A valid user token must be passed."
}

Where do I set this token?(which field?)

Can somebody describe steps which i need do for load information about video?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need to authenticate your requests. You need to use OAuth to authenticate a user account with the Vimeo API. Then once the user has logged in, you can access the video thumbnail.

This tutorial may be of use: http://codegerms.com/login-with-vimeo-in-ios-app-using-oauth-tutorial/

**Update**

There are some endpoints which the Vimeo API supports without any authentication whatsoever. Take a look at this Vimeo Developer page: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication (Make sure you scroll to the "Unauthenticated Requests" section).

Comment: I have taken token. So where  I need set it data?